# Runnning total of unique string values in column over days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an sql table of device logins that looks like:

```
date,        username,      devicename
2018-09-05,  bricew,       brice-pc
2018-09-05,  bricew,       brice-laptop
2018-09-06,  bricew,       brice-laptop
2018-09-06,  bricew,       brice-ipad
2018-09-06,  johnm,        john-pc
2018-09-06,  bricew,       brice-laptop
```

How can I get a running total of unique devices per username per day?
I want a column that would look like this for the example:

```
running_total
1
2
2
3
1
3
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/  this is an extremely basic SQL query that is readily available in probably all SQL tutorials on counting.

Comment: @dfundako no it's not. It's not available in *any* introductory tutorials either. It's typically found in *advanced* tutorials that talk about analytic functions and windowing

Comment: Consider reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and taking a [Tour of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), then coming back and editing your question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 'SQL Server running total' in Google provides quite a bit of info along with lots of basic examples, which this query would fall under.

Comment: @dfundako yes, I already said so. And explained what the correct answer is because it's *NOT* a trivial question with a lot of answers that don't apply since 2012. Check Gordon's answer to understand why that's *not* a basic question covered in all tutorials

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Cool

Comment: @dfundako in fact, it looks like the usual `running total` techniques don't work with `COUNT()` ?

Comment: What have you tried so far???  SO is not a free coding service!!!

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has window functions.  So, it would seem that you could do:

```
select t.*,
       count(distinct devicename) over (partition by date, username) as running_total
from t;
```

Alas, support for window functions does not extend to this use of `count(distinct)`.  You can do this, using a subquery.  One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by date, username) as running_total
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date, username, device_name order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Another method uses `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       max(seqnum) over (partition by date, username) as running_total
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by date, username order by device_name) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```